# Add 10k+ rows to a Class in Parse Server

Tags: mongodb, import, parse-server

I've got 10k+ new questions objects to my Question class (therefore they don't have objectIds for now). I want to add them to my dashboard. On Parse.com, I would have uploaded a CSV. But Parse Server and its open source dashboard don't allow this functionality.

Here is what I tried so far :

- Use `mongoimport` to upload a JSON. All went well. But the created `objectIds` are really long (Ex:`577b7488e9d6261a308ed262`) and curiously resembling to each other . They all have at least 80% of the characters in common. And any object that points to a question fetch nothing when trying to fetch the question. So I guessed that bypassing parse server to create objects was a bad idea.
- Write a node script to upload the question using Parse `save` method. But 10k+ objects is way too big and the script always end up failing.
- Use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/davimacedo/c7738203a2a616b48a22fdc7c00b37d2) that combines curl and cloud code. But my curl request is too

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Your curl request is too ... what?  What does your node script fail?  What's the error?  Can you post the script?

Comment: Solved it like this: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/2220